# How can I match Regex with multiple unicode properties with AND (JavaScript)?

Tags: regex, unicode, properties, cjk, non-ascii-characters

I want to match characters via regex on:

- `/\p{Script=Han}/gu` AND `/\p{Alphabetic}/gu`

This would mean that:

- `﨑` matches, it's both Han and Alphabetic
- `〆` doesn't match, it's alphabetic but not Han
- `⺁` doesn't match, it's Han but not alphabetic (it's a radical)

Ideally someone can show me how to do it with browser-based JavaScript.

PS:

I was using this before: `/[\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]/g`
but the issue is that it won't match all Han characters like `﨑` so I rather use `/\p{Script=Han}/gu` but avoid any non-alphabetic characters like radicals etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead assertion to match only Alphabetic results that also match Han with something like the following:

```js
const expr = /(?=\p{Script=Han})\p{Alphabetic}/gu;
```

This gives your desired output I believe